# How did this soft mutation happened?

Tags: etymology, morphology, celtic, welsh, mutation

The mutations in the Welsh language were originated from elements that came before words and affected them etc.

How does the fact that a certain noun is the direct object of a sentence trigger a soft mutation?

Eg.:

> *Gwelais i **geffyl**.* (I saw a horse)

*Geffyl* being the soft mutation of *ceffyl*.

Was there an object marked lost in time that existed in proto-celtic? Maybe the verb's inflection itself caused it? Or is there a different explanation (or no explanation at all)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theory is that "soft mutation" is the result of intervocalic lenition. [This paper](https://www.uni-due.de/~lan300/13_Initial_Mutation_in_Celtic_(Hickey).pdf) on Celtic in general may help you to navigate the details of the branches of Celtic, plus gives references for earlier historical works (Thurneysen, Pedersen, Windisch), and [this paper](https://www.uibk.ac.at/anglistik/staff/herdina/englishinhistory/old_and_middle_welsh.pdf) §2.2.2 for more focus on Welsh. The more-remote claim regarding Indo-European is that the categories triggering soft mutation were originally vowel-final morphemes, but then the phonetic causes were obliterated and the process was morphologized. [This page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Welsh_mutations) gathers together an impressive array of contexts where various mutations occur in Welsh the relation between synchronic conditioning and diachronic cause is completely non-obvious.